# Using list comprehension for repeated function calls in Python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

In my current codebase, I have the following line where `to_remove` is a set

```
 [to_remove.update(b) for b in some_set if all(a <= b for a in some_dict)]
```

Although it works, it bothers me a little bit since it creates a list of `None` which is not used. Is it considered not standard? Is there a better way to do it?

**Update:**

Since it has been pointed out that list comprehension solely for side effect is not good, I have changed my code to

```
to_remove.update(itertools.chain.from_iterable(
    b for b in some_set if all(a <= b for a in some_dict))
```

Comment: Side effects inside a list comprehension are unusual and unexpected, which makes them a very bad idea. Anything that confuses people and has a more straightforward implementation should be avoided.

Comment: An ordinary for loop and an if statement?

Comment: You have to do it this way `to_remove.update([b for b in some_set if all(a <= b for a in some_dict)])`

Comment: @A-B-B Ah you made it into an iterable. Yes that is good, although might confuse (Python) beginners.

Answer (score 2):

It's not standard or recommended to use a list comprehension if its output is not assigned to a variable. A static analyzer such as `pylint` will even flag it.

Use a conventional loop instead:

```
for b in some_set:
    if all(a <= b for a in some_dict):
        to_remove.update(b)
```

In your specific case, since `to_remove` is a set, the following may or may not work correctly:

```
to_remove.update(b for b in some_set if all(a <= b for a in some_dict))
```

Comment: `to_remove.update(b for b in some_set if all(a <= b for a in some_dict))` does not give the same result